# Why is Index Error arising(tuple index out of range)?

Tags: python, django

Actually,I am working on a Django project which uses sql.Whenever I try to go to a particular link on the site.The referenced page does not open and it shows tuple index out of range.The error is sbowing on line
23 of the code.I can't understand the reason behind it.The indices seem to be okay.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    key_word = form.cleaned_data['search']
    key_word = '%' + key_word + '%'

    context = {}
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute('SELECT * ' +
                           'FROM `author` ' +
                           'WHERE `id` = %s;', [self.request.user.author_id, ])
            row = cursor.fetchone()

            context['username'] = row[1]

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = """SELECT `publication`.`id`, `title`, `description`, `date`, `location`, `publisher`.`id`,
                 `publisher`.`name`, `publisher`.`type`
                 FROM `publication`, `publisher`
                 WHERE `approved`=TRUE AND (`title` LIKE %s OR `description` LIKE %s);"""

        cursor.execute(sql, [key_word, key_word])
        tbl = cursor.fetchall()
        if tbl is not None and tbl[0] is not None:
            context['publications'] = []
            for row in tbl:
                get_publication(row, context)

    return render(self.request, 'portal/search.html', context)
```

Comment: Why do you use "raw queries" iso Django's ORM?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem actually  I am working on another  person's project.But the person can't be contacted.